# What are the differences between Math.(E|PI) and those of StrictMath?

Tags: java, math, constants, pi

I just found that [`java.lang.StrictMath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StrictMath.html) has [`E`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StrictMath.html#E) and [`PI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StrictMath.html#PI) which each is also available in [`java.lang.Math`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html).

Are there any differences between them?

I check the source([`Math`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Math.java), [`StrictMath`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/StrictMath.java)) and found they are the same values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, of course not.  They're constants, you don't need to store them with different levels of precision.